# What is the use of "Create New Wifi Network" option available in wifi settings of devices?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android

Can Anyone explain me the use of Create new wifi network option available in wifi settings of Devices (Android/PC etc.)

Example Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6CpE.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes the device act as a wireless router (i.e. switches Wi-Fi to "access point" mode and serves DHCP) so that other devices could connect to it.

This is exactly the same thing as the "Hotspot" feature in Android or iOS.

The purpose is to allow you to temporarily share another type of Internet connection (e.g. LTE or Ethernet) over Wi-Fi, without having a separate wireless router.

Answer (score -1):

Umm the 1st answer is correct but in this case the option `access point` or other name is available.
I think is other thing is for connect to a secret wifi network , is a manual connection.
https://youtu.be/g6Y3Kt02m4o
this is a video , is in spanish but you can use the cc.
About the video I can explain:
You can configure the Wifi Network without being in the place and when you return to the place it will be , you can also find hidden wifi. You need a Name of the hidden network.
And the SSI Name and the security type.

Comment: Link only answer is useless. Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: what i need explain? is not simple ? only a form to connect a wifi ... you can watch the video is about the manual connection.

Comment: @V4T1C4N0 - Answers which only contained a link are not considered to be answered, since without the link the answer is not helpful.  Without the link to the video, your answer does not answer the author's question.  Answers on Super User are expected to be in English, this includes, the external references they use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Community thanks i need learn about the how to write good answers.